# Laravel Blade - custom helper

Tags: laravel, format, helper, laravel-blade

I have table with a lot of numbers and I want to use number format for all of them. So right now I have this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($table['float']['chips_amount'] as $float)
        <tr>
            <td class="no-border"></td>
            <td class="text-right chip-width">{{ number_format($float['chips']['value'], 0, ' ', ' ') }}</td>
            <td class="text-right count-width">{{ $float['count'] }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($float['chips']['value'] * $float['count'], 0, ' ', ' ') }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td class="no-border" colspan="3"></td>
        <td class="text-right value-width bold-border">{{ number_format($table['float']['amount'], 0, ' ', ' ') }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I'm just repeating the same function number_format() and there could be problem when somebody decide that format will be different. Then I have to change all formats in table. I have some experience with Nette framework and there exists option that I can have custom helper and then use it in template, i.e: `{{ $anyNumber|myCustomFormat }}` where after pipeline I have my own custom helper. Is there something like that in Laravel Blade templates? I didn't find anything about this in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own blade help file.
Create you file (say in *app/Helpers/bladeHelpers.php*) and add code. For example;

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('my_custom_number_formt')) {
    /**
     * Format number
     *
     * @param $value
     * @param $attribute
     * @param $data
     * @return boolean
     */
    function my_custom_number_formt($value)
    {

        return number_format($value, 0, ' ', ' ');

    }

}
```

Then add this file to your *composer.json* in the **autoload** section (remember to set the namespace as per your project in the psr4 declaration);

```
{
... rest of file
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "MyApp\\Custom\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/bladeHelpers.php"
        ]
    },
... rest of file
}
```

N.B You may want to clear your cache at this point.

Then use in your blade files;

```
<td class="text-right chip-width">{{ my_custom_number_formt($float['chips']['value']) }}</td>
```